# Reading each row from text file into an array of doubles or integer using C#

Tags: c#, arrays

Suppose I have a text file with data like below, I want to read first row and store the elements in one array. Read the second row and store in second array and so on. I will be making some manipulations on the array later on. Can you help me to do this in C#?

**Input text file:**

5,7,3,6,9,8,3,5,7

5,6,8,3,4,5

6,4,3,2,65,8,6,3,3,5,7,4

4,5,6,78,9,4,2,5,6

***The Code I am trying out is:***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace ReadFile
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TextReader tr = new StreamReader("Data.txt");
            // write a line of text to the file
            string word = tr.ReadLine();
            //now split this line into words
            string[] val = word.Split(new Char[] { ',' });
        }
    }

}
```

***If I use the above technique, I can get the first line in array val. Is there a way to loop it for all the rows?***

Comment: Its good to begin at some point! But what have you tried yet? Can you paste your code in the question.

Comment: Good i see that you have posted what you have tried, what you are expecting OR what is desired AND the problem. Now you will get good answers!

Comment: I am expecting to use each row data as a sample for analysis. Once I get an array for each row, I can use them for my analysis.

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem?

Comment: I am still working on it. I was trying out the method given by Phil Cartmell below, I am not able to pre determine the number of rows thus created, so I can use an array to work on the individual rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Thanks all for your time!

```
private void ReadFile()
    {
        var lines = File.ReadLines("Data.csv");
        var numbers = new List<List<double>>();
        var separators = new[] { ',', ' ' };
        /*System.Threading.Tasks.*/
        Parallel.ForEach(lines, line =>
        {
            var list = new List<double>();
            foreach (var s in line.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                double i;

                if (double.TryParse(s, out i))
                {
                    list.Add(i);
                }
            }

            lock (numbers)
            {
                numbers.Add(list);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

[File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx) will help you read all lines from file as string array.
[String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) will help you split line in pieces.
[Int.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse.aspx) will help you transform string to int (double has similar method).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, since you are a beginner my suggestions on what to focalize your attention.
First of all, are your consumer always needing all the lines or can it stop at some point? If so, use a [yield](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) strategy to return the results one by one. You can use a [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) to read line one by one in any case, and use [double.TryParse(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/994c0zb1.aspx) or [int.TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/f02979c7.aspx) after [splitting the string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) by the separator. Keep an eye to the fact that separator can change, so use it with some kind of configurability, and in the case of double, ensure your code works even in machines with a different decimal point configured. If you are sure your csv alwais uses `'.'` as a decimal point separator, specify

```
double.TryParse("",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

See this lines of code:

```
List<List<int>> numbers = new List<List<int>>();
foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(""))
{
    var list = new List<int>();
    foreach (string s in line.Split(new[]{',', ' '}, 
                                    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    {
        int i;
        if(int.TryParse(s, out i))
        {
            list.Add(i);
        }
    }
    numbers.Add(list);
}

var specialNumber = numbers[3][4];        // gives line 3 number 4
var specialLine = numbers[2].ToArray();   //  gives an array of numbers of line 2
```

**description:**
I used this useful Generic:

- [`List`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx): Represents a strongly typed list of objects that can be accessed by index

and these useful Classes:

- [`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx): Opens a text file, reads all lines of the file into a string array
- [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) : Returns a string array that contains the substrings in this instance that are delimited by elements of a specified string or Unicode character array.
- [`Int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7): Converts the string representation of a number to its 32-bit signed integer equivalent.

Comment: This will give one array for all lines, but the OP asked for one array per line.

Comment: This adds the numbers to the same array, each line should be in it's own array so you would need an list of int[].

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<int[]> arrays = new List<int[]>();

            int counter = 0;
            string line;

            // Read the file
            System.IO.StreamReader file =
               new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\temp\\test.txt");
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                // split the line into a string array on , separator
                string[] splitLine = line.ToString().Split(',');

                // if our split isnt null and has a positive length
                if (splitLine != null && splitLine.Length > 0)
                {

                    // create a lineArray the same size as our new string[]
                    int[] lineArray = new int[splitLine.Length];

                    int posCounter = 0;

                    foreach (string splitValue in splitLine)
                    {
                        // loop through each value in the split, try and convert
                        // it into an int and push it into the array
                        try
                        {
                            lineArray[posCounter] = Int32.Parse(splitValue);
                        }
                        catch { }
                        posCounter++;
                    }

                    // if our lineArray has a positive length then at it to our
                    // list of arrays for processing later.
                    if (lineArray.Length > 0)
                    {
                        arrays.Add(lineArray);
                    }
                }
                counter++;
            }

            file.Close();

            // go through the List<int[]> and print to screen
            foreach (int[] row in arrays)
            {
                foreach (int rowCol in row)
                {
                    Console.Write(rowCol + ",");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            // Suspend the screen.
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you find length of each row array? Also when do the rows stop?

Comment: You can find the number of values in each row with splitLine.Length What do you mean by when the do rows stop?

Comment: How can I find the total number of rows in the file? If I need to store the size of each row in another array, do I need another for loop or can I just assign it inside the while loop?

Comment: Since we are appending the rows one after the other inside the while loop, we cannot find the number of rows prior to give the size of the new array to store row sizes.

I would like to use say, row[1] as a sample for some calculations, then use the next row and so on, preferably in a for loop. I was thinking it can be done if the number of rows is known prior so we can use the for loop.

Comment: How about just picking random items from the arrays list

Comment: I want to use the entire array list. One after the other preferable.

Comment: well thats what the foreach (int[] row in arrays) does towards the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Something roughly like this would work:

```
StreamReader reader = new (File.OpenRead(@"YourFile.txt"));
List<string> LstIntegers = new List<string>();

            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                //values is actually a string array.
                var values = line.Split(',');
                //add the entire array fetched into string List
        LstIntegers.AddRange(values);   
            }
          // important to close the reader. You can also use using statement for reader. It 
          // will close the reader automatically when reading finishes.
            reader.Close();

   // You can then further manipulate it like below, you can also use int.Parse or int.TryParse:
   foreach (var v in LstIntegers)
   {
      // use int.TryParse if there is a chance that a non-int is read.
      int someNum = Convert.ToInt32(v);

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have presented the following code in two sections, just to show you in steps.

### SECTION 1

This code is just to show that you just needed to loop through all lines and store string numbers from each line in a List.

SECTION 1

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     List<string[]> allLines = new List<string[]>();

     TextReader tr = new StreamReader("Data.txt");
     string word = tr.ReadLine();

     // write a line of text to the file
     while ( word !=  null ) {

         //now split this line into words
         string[] vals = word.Split(new Char[] { ',' });

         //Add this line into allLines
         allLines.Add(vals);

         //Now read the next line
         word = tr.ReadLine();
     }
}
```

---

### SECTION 2

This section will get you the results as `int`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     //A list of arrays of integers
     //A single array will have numbers from a single line
     List<int[]> allNumbers = new List<int[]>();

     TextReader tr = new StreamReader("Data.txt");
     string word = tr.ReadLine();

     // write a line of text to the file
     while ( word !=  null ) {

         //now split this line into words
         string[] vals = word.Split(new Char[] { ',' });
         int[] intVals = new int[vals.Length];

         for ( int i = 0; i < vals.Length; i++) {
             Int32.TryParse(vals[i], out intVals[i]);
         }

         //Add this array of integers into allNumbers
         allNumbers.Add(intVals);

         //Now read the next line
         word = tr.ReadLine();
     }
}
```

NOTE: I have not compiled or tested the code above.